# Receiving parameters with APIView

Tags: python, django, routes, restful-url

I have this routing:

```
   url(r'^article/(?P<article_id>\d+)/', views.ArticleList.as_view())
```

which leads to this function:

```
class RSSList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article_id = kwargs.get('article_id')
```

But when I try to query something like /article/34

I get this error:

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'article_id'
```

How can I pass article_id to get()?

Thank you

Comment: `RSSList` is not the problem, you are missing `*args, **kwargs` somewhere else. Maybe in `ArticleList` instead of `RSSList`?

Comment: You're using `ArticleList` class in your routing! But you're fetching `article_id` inside of `RSSList` class instead!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get like this also:

```
def get(self, request, article_id):
   print(article_id) #for >3.2
   print article_id # for 2.7
```

If you want to make it optional:

```
def get(self, request, article_id=None):
```

Comment: And how to register this optional or not parameter?